# Trying to run some c# code in my PowerShell script

Tags: c#, powershell, grouping, taskbar

I'm looking for a way to use the following C# code in my PowerShell script:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern void SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string AppID);
SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID("MyAUMID");
```

My Windows application starts another application, which is basically PowerShell script compiled with PS1 to Exe. I'm trying to see if I can have both exe files grouped on the taskbar by giving them the same AUMID. Does anybody know how to run this C# code in my PowerShell script? I think I need to use something like:

```
$loadLibrary = @'
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern void SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID( [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string AppID );
'@
```

But I don't know how to use the `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID()` properly.
Thanks for any help in advance!

Kind regards, Eric

Comment: Right click on SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID in c# and select and select GO TO DEFINITION.  What libraries (namespace) is it using.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391367/dllimport-in-powershell-for-accessing-c-style-32-bit-api-using-relative-path?force_isolation=true

Comment: `$winapi = Add-Type -PassThru -Namespace shell32 -name aumid -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError=true)] public static extern void SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID( [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string AppID );'; $winapi::SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID('FooBar')`

Comment: I'm not sure if this even works from PowerShell as the docs say: _"This method must be called during an application's initial startup routine before the application presents any UI [...]"_. So it might be too late for your PowerShell script.

Comment: Hi @zett42 Thank you very much for your help. Although my script issues no errors (and thus your code should be working) it doesn't seem to be working after compiling the script. Bummer. Anyway, it was worth trying. I appreciated your help! Kind regards, Eric